# For real numbers $z$ and $w$, $|(1+z)(1+w)-1| \leq (1+|z|)(1+|w|)-1$.

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I have written an attempted proof of the theorem on the title, and I need help verifying it.
I have used the following theorems to proof the theorem on the title.

**Theorem 5.14)a)** Let $x$ be a real number. $-|x| \leq x \leq |x|$.

**Theorem 5.14)b)** Let $a \geq 0$. $|x| \leq a$ if and only if $-a \leq x \leq a$.

**Theorem 5.14)c)** Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers. $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$ (The Triangle Inequality).

---

For real numbers $z$ and $w$, $|(1+z)(1+w)-1| \leq (1+|z|)(1+|w|)-1$.

Proof. From **Theorem 5.14)a)**, $(1+z) \leq |(1+z)|$ and $(1+w) \leq |(1+w)|$. Multiplying the $(1+z) \leq |(1+z)|$ by $|(1+w)|$, one obtains

\begin{align}
(1+z)|(1+w)| \leq |(1+z)||(1+w)|
\end{align}

Since $(1+w) \leq |(1+w)|$, it follows that

\begin{align}
(1+z)(1+w) \leq |(1+z)||(1+w)|
\end{align}

Observe that from The Triangle Inequality,

\begin{align}
|(1+z)| \leq 1 + |z|\\
|(1+w)| \leq 1 + |w|
\end{align}

Since $|(1+z)|(1 + |w|) \leq (1 + |z|)(1 + |w|)$ and $|(1+w)| \leq (1 + |w|)$, it follows that

\begin{align}
(1+z)(1+w) -1 \leq |(1+z)||(1+w)| -1 \leq (1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1
\end{align}

It is clear that $(1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1 \geq 0$.

In case that $(1+z)(1+w) -1 \geq 0$, $|(1+z)(1+w) -1| = (1+z)(1+w) -1$.

Hence,

\begin{align}
-[(1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1] \leq 0 \leq (1+z)(1+w) -1 \leq (1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1
\end{align}

From **Theorem 5.14)b)**,

\begin{align}
|(1+z)(1+w) -1| \leq (1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1
\end{align}

establishing the result for this case.

On the other hand, in case that $(1+z)(1+w) -1 < 0$, $|(1+z)(1+w) -1| = -[(1+z)(1+w) -1]$.

Hence,

\begin{align}
-[(1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1] \leq (1+z)(1+w) -1 < 0
\end{align}

Since $(1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1 \geq 0$,

\begin{align}
-[(1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1] \leq (1+z)(1+w) -1 \leq (1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1
\end{align}

Multiplying the inequalities by $-1$, one obtains

\begin{align}
(1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1 \geq -[(1+z)(1+w) -1] \geq -[(1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1]
\end{align}

From **Theorem 5.14)b)**,

\begin{align}
|(1+z)(1+w) -1| \leq (1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1
\end{align}

establishing the result for this case.

Because the result for all cases of $(1+z)(1+w) -1$ have been established, it is the case that $|(1+z)(1+w) -1| \leq (1 + |z|)(1 + |w|) -1$.

---

Comment: Were these Theorems and the problem from Daepp & Gorkin's book, "Reading, Writing, and Proving"? I am working through it as well and I believe you can just use the Triangle Inequality twice to prove the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the `solution-verification` part of the question, this step is wrong.

> one obtains
>
> \begin{align}
> (1+z)|(1+w)| \leq |(1+z)||(1+w)|
> \end{align}
>
> Since $(1+w) \leq |(1+w)|$, it follows that
>
> \begin{align}
> (1+z)(1+w) \leq |(1+z)||(1+w)|
> \end{align}

The above is of the form $\, a \cdot |b| \le c \implies a \cdot b \le c\,$, which does not hold true in general. For example, if $\,a=b=-2, \,c=1\,$ then $\,a \cdot |b| = -4 \le 1 = c\,$, but $\,a \cdot b = 4 \gt 1 = c\,$. The implication does hold true for $\,a \ge 0\,$, but here $\,a = 1 + z\,$ which is not necessarily positive.

The correct way to derive the inequality is to use that $\,|a \cdot b| = |a| \cdot |b|\,$, then:

$$
(1+z)\cdot (1+w) \;\leq\; |(1+z)\cdot(1+w)| \;=\; |1+z|\cdot|1+w|
$$

Comment: But in this case $c$ is not any real numbers. It is $|a||b|$ where $a = 1+z$ and $b = 1+w$ in which Theorem 5.14)a) have stated that $ab \leq |ab|$. Hence, why is it not the case that $a\cdot |b| \leq |a||b|$?

Comment: @Approxiz The inequality you get in the end is correct, but the justification as-written is not. "*Since $(1+w) \leq |(1+w)|$, it follows that...*" sounds like you take $(1+w) \leq |(1+w)|$ and multiply it by $1+z$ to get $(1+z)\cdot(1+w) \color{red}{\leq} (1+z) \cdot |(1+w)| \le |1+z| \cdot |1+w|$ but the first $\color{red}{\le}$ does not hold true in general. The end result is, again, correct, so you *can* justify that step in a different way - for example as proposed in my answer, or hinted in your comment here.

Answer (score 3):

We have :

$(1+z)(1+w)-1 = z+w+zw$

Thus :

$|(1+z)(1+w)-1| = |z+w+zw| \le |z| + |w| + |zw| = (1+|z|)(1+|w|) -1$

QED

Comment: Is there any mistake on my attempted proof? , and thank you for the shorter version of the proof.

Comment: Not that I could spot, but it is quite convoluted